# Store results of a polyfit in a for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Consider the following code, which makes up a random data set and fits polynomials of order 1 to 5 against the data:

```
x=1:100;
data=exp(-rand(1).*x);

for ii = 1:1:5;
polyfit(x,data,ii);
end
```

I am wondering what is the most elegant way to store the polyfit coefficients during each loop? I thought

```
fitCoef(ii,:) = polyfit(x,data,ii)
```

would work but i am getting a `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error at the `ii = 2` iteration. I understand why, because it is trying to put a vector of 3 values into a vector who's length is only 2... but am not sure how to properly resolve this problem.

My ideal output is a matrix which displays the coefficients on each row so e.g.

`p(1) p(2)`

`p(1) p(2) p(3)`

`p(1) p(2) p(3) p(4)`

But I don't know how to deal with the black spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialise a matrix of zeros before beginning the loop, using `fitCoeffs=zeros(5,6)`. This wont affect `polyval`.

You could also save the results into a cell array, `fitCoeffs{ii}=polyfit(x,data,ii)`, then to use each set of coefficients do, for example, `polyval(fitCoeffs{3},X)`.

I've illustrated both options below:

```
x=1:100;
data=exp(-rand(1).*x);
N=5;
P=zeros(N,N+1);
P2=cell(1,N);
for ii = 1:N;
    P(ii,1:ii+1)=polyfit(x,data,ii);
    P2{ii}=polyfit(x,data,ii);
end

P
P2

polyval(P(3,:),1)
polyval(P(3,1:4),1) % Note it doesn't matter if you leave the zeros in

polyval(P2{3},1)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, these 2 methods are just what I am after

Answer (score 3):

You could skip the for loop entirely as well:

```
A = cellfun(@(degree) polyfit(x, data, degree), num2cell(1:5), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. I do like using cellfun and arrayfun when I can, but never seem to be able to pick the right moment lol, I guess any time there is a for loop I should consider the usability of one of those `fun` commands...

Comment: @SteveHatcher certainly not any time.Those ``cellfun``, ``bsxfun`` and ``arrayfun`` solutions look neat, but it is not guaranteed that they are the fastest solution. In fact, there are often times situations in which they are slower. Bit this solution looks very nice and by choosing the variable names as they are it is perfectly readable. +1

Comment: Nras raises a good point - cellfun can often introduce some unwanted overhead if you're not careful.  I ran into an odd one the other day - `cellfun(@(x) mean(x) ...)` was ~3x slower than `cellfun(@(x) sum(x)/length(x) ...)`